# Fixing uninitialized constant OpenSSL::Digest::DSS on Mac OS Sierra with RVM

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

I just solved a difficult problem on my Mac (High Sierra) and wanted to share so others can fix it more quickly than it took me.

The specific error was `uninitialized constant OpenSSL::Digest::DSS` when trying to use any Ruby gem that used Net::SSH.  In my case the Net::SFTP gem would not connect to any server.

At first I tried `bundle update net-ssh`, but that didn't fix it.

Then I decided that this is probably a Ruby issue and `openssl` isn't linked properly.

Comment: If possible please write your own answer and remove the answer from your question. Also don't hesitate to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to get this right, but ultimately the following worked:

```
rvm reinstall 2.4.2 --with-openssl-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
```

It'll take a while to reinstall because rvm will run `rvm pristine`, but when its done just run `bundle install` again and you should be good to go.

To verify, just open your console via `irb` or `rails console` and enter:

`OpenSSL::Digest::DSS`

That module should exist after you're done.

Comment: Thanks! But this does not work.
I run 
rvm reinstall 2.4.2 --with-openssl-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
bundle install

Still now working. 

I run openssl version, it returns: 
LibreSSL 2.8.3

My colleage 2.6.5 works, which has OpenSSL::Digest::DSS1

Comment: I wrote this almost 2 years ago for OS X High Sierra.  If you're not using OS X 10.13, this answer may not work for you.  Sorry.

Comment: yeah, its catalina now. Thanks for reply.